# Non-ascii character transformed in ? in Spring rest endpoint for multipart files

Tags: spring, non-ascii-characters, spring-restcontroller

Is there any chance to configure spring to accept non ascii characters for filenames?

That's how my endpoint signature look like:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/file/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST,
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadFile(
 @RequestParam("files") List<MultipartFile> files, Principal principal) {
```

If I send a file with name åäö_test.txt it arrives as ???_test.txt.

Thanks.